# How to open a response in a new window/tab via servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I used to have two forms in my HTML Page each with a button inside that submits it. The second one looks like this and generates a PDF:

```
<form action="/MyProject/print" method="post" name="printForm"
    onsubmit="return validateForm()" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" id="pdf_button" class="button"
        name="print" value="${buttonPrint}"> 
</form>
```

For page flow I need to place both buttons in one form and handle it in the servlet. I wonder how can I achieve the PDFis served in a new window?

I use following which does work, but forwards to the PDF in the same window. How could I set the target to `_blank`?

```
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/print").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone issues the same problem, here is how I got around:

I added an onsubmit event to the form via JavaScript which catches the pressed submit button and changes the target & action if it was the pdf button.

```
$("form").submit(
                function() {
                    var val = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr(
                            'id');
                    if (val == 'pdf_button') {
                        $("#myForm").attr('target', '_blank');
                        $("#myForm").attr(
                                'action',
                                /Path/To/Print/Servlet
                    }
                });
        $("form input[type=submit]").click(
                function() {
                    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form"))
                            .removeAttr("clicked");
                    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
                });
```